# Python find indexes of list of lists

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to find the indexes of all the elements in a python list of lists. The list would look something like this:

```
list = [[x,y,x],
        [x,y,y],
        [y,y,y]]
```

To do this I have tried to use a nested loop like this:

```
for lst in list:
        print(list.index(lst))
        for x in lst:
            print(lst.index(x))
```

This however prints out a long list with almost seemingly random numbers.

[screenshot of output for a slightly different list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSP4m.png)

What I'm tring to achieve is an output looking something like this:

```
0
1
0
2
0
3
1
0
1
0
```

Is there anyone who can help out a python beginner?

Comment: Your input has 9 items, why do you want 10 numbers as output?

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate to print indexes

```
x = 22
y = 34

l = [[x,y,x],
        [x,y,y],
        [y,y,y]]

indexes = [(i, j) for i, nl in enumerate(l) for j, nle in enumerate(nl)]
print(*indexes, sep="\n")

# output
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access index and value with the use of by looping thorugh the list using `enumerate`. I added some printing with text to show what number is what.

```
myList = [[1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]]

for lstIdx, lst in enumerate(myList):
    print("list idx: " + str(lstIdx))
    for idx, item in enumerate(lst):
        print("item idx in list: " + str(idx))
```

output:

```
list idx: 0
item idx in list: 0
item idx in list: 1
item idx in list: 2
list idx: 1
item idx in list: 0
item idx in list: 1
item idx in list: 2
list idx: 2
item idx in list: 0
item idx in list: 1
item idx in list: 2
```